# NiFi- how to http post a PDF document

Tags: pdf, post, apache-nifi

I wanted to use NiFi's **posthttp/invokeHttp** processor to post a PDF to an API.

But considering the following cURL request to replicate in NiFi:

```
curl -X POST "http://ipaddress:port/api/" -H "accept: application/json" -H 
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "pdf_file=@sample.pdf;
        type=application/pdf"
```

Which property takes the `-F` information in nifi attributes?

Configuration for invokehttp right now:
[image]
[image]
error:
"400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Configration for posthttp right now:
[image]
error:
server logs: readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream

Comment: The -F curl parameter sends file as one of the parts of multipart/form-data. So, you have to convert your flowfile(PDF) to this format... Short description here https://ec.haxx.se/http-multipart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older version of nifi you will have to use your own script to build a multipart request and then use invoke to create post request. You can refer to this post for a ExecuteGroovyScript example.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204862

Since Nifi 1.12 you can directly use invokeHTTP by setting content-type
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69284300

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you use PostHttp/InvokeHttp you wouldn't be referencing an external file, you would be sending the content of the flow file. So you would first need to bring sample.pdf into NiFi by using GetFile or ListFile/FetchFile and then flow file coming out of those processors represents the PDF, and you would route that flow file to InvokeHttp which would POST the content of the flow file (the pdf).

Comment: i already have a pdf as a flowfile in the input stream to the invokehttp processor. But it doesn't seem to send the pdf as per the above curl format hence I get an internal server error

Comment: Can you show your configuration of the InvokeHttp processor as well as the stacktrace of the exception from nifi-app.log?

Comment: added the details for your review

Comment: What Content-Type is the server expecting? In your example curl command it has "Content-Type: multipart/form-data", and in the InvokeHttp it has ${mime.type}, did you set mime.type to multipart/form-data before this processor? Otherwise its likely that mime.type is application/pdf or maybe not set, wondering if that is causing the bad request

Comment: no I tried all combinations for that in both the processors

Comment: Are there any logs on your server as to why it is rejecting the request with a 400? That might give more info about what is considered bad in the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190101/discussion-between-identity1-and-bryan-bende).

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Was it resolved in chat?  The chat isn't accessible at work.