# Posting multiple files using invokehttp to API using nifi

Tags: api, apache-nifi

I am having 3 files which i need to post to API end. I am fetching 3 files using FetchHDFS process and i want to pass them to API. How can i pass them.

**Input:**

```
3 files in HDFS
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

**Error:**

```
invokehttp.response.body
{ "message": "Multipart: Boundary not found (user: 'undefined')", "level": "error", "timestamp": "2019-12-11T09:59:05.464Z" }
```

**Flow tried:**

```
inputPort --> 3 FetchHDFS process to fetch 3 different file --> invokeHttps
```

curl commnad sample:

```
curl -X POST "https://xxxxxx/xxxxx" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file1=@File1.csv;type=application/vnd.ms-excel" -F "file2=@File2.txt;type=text/plain" -F "file3=@File3.csv;type=application/vnd.ms-excel" -F "format=flat"
```

Comment: Boundary issue was resolved when i am passing content type value as "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" , but unable to pass file. updated sample curl command i am trying to implement and working.

Comment: there was a question how to [build multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122809/nifi-multipart-form) in nifi. however to  convert several flow files into one multipart some effort required...

Comment: trying something like this....

        .addTextBody( "master", ff.File1 ) //get from flowfile attribute "filename"
        .addTextBody( "compare", ff.File2 ) //add text body from file
        .addBinaryBody( "avatar", streamIn, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, ff.File1 )
  .addBinaryBody( "avatar", streamIn, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, ff.File2 )

will this work? i am new to groovy

Answer (score 0):

The idea: Before building multipart from several flow files you need to merge them into one.

For this use the `MergeContent` processor with `Merge Format = TAR`.

Then use `ExecuteGroovyScript` to convert `TAR` to `multipart`.

```groovy
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpmime', version='4.5.9')
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-compress', version='1.19')
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return

//delegate inputstream class to be able to set the `delegate` later
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class TarContentInputStream extends InputStream{
    @Delegate TarArchiveInputStream delegate
    @Override void close(){
        println "--------- try to close"
        if(!delegate.getNextTarEntry())delegate.close()
    }
}

def multipart = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
def tarContent = new TarContentInputStream()

//iterate through TAR entries and build multipart
def tarInput=new TarArchiveInputStream(ff.read())
def tarEntry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry()
while (tarEntry != null) {
    //reference tarContent to be used as body
    multipart.addBinaryBody( tarEntry.getName(), tarContent, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, tarEntry.getName() )
    tarEntry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry()
}
tarInput.close()
//write multipart content
ff.write{streamIn, streamOut->
    //set real input stream to be used as tar content
    tarContent.delegate = new TarArchiveInputStream(streamIn)
    assert tarContent.delegate.getNextTarEntry() //move to first entry
    multipart = multipart.build()
    multipart.writeTo(streamOut)
}

ff."mime.type" = multipart.getContentType().getValue()
ff.filename = ff.filename+".multipart"

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

---

Note:

for 3 test files combined into `tar` the code above produces something like:

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1.txt"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

file1 content
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2.txt"; filename="file2.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

file2 content
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file3.txt"; filename="file3.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

file3 content
--boundary--
```

Currently code scans input stream two times: 1st - to scan tar entries, 2nd - to build content.

I think it's possible to rewrite the code to convert tar to multipart in one shot...

Comment: Thanks dagget :), is there anyway to dynamically pass other naming convention to filename variable, like MainFile= file1.txt, secondayFile=file2.txt , some thing like this?

Comment: before merging into one tar set `filename` with `updateattribute` processor to what you need for each file. (if I understood you right...)