# nifi invokehttp multipart/form-data support

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to make invokeHTTP processor to send multipart/form-data request, and I cant figure out how.

1. Does it support it? Can I set the Content-Type property to  multipart/form-data  ?
2. How should I add my FlowFile to the body under the right form ?
3. How can I add forms?

Thanks!

Comment: [See this question for an updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69284300/3955972)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes - you could set multipart/form-data
2. you have to build the multipart/form-data format (no build-in nifi methods)
3. links below

multipart with one file: [Nifi multipart form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122809/nifi-multipart-form/57204862#57204862)

multipart with multiple files: [Posting multiple files using invokehttp to API using nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374728/posting-multiple-files-using-invokehttp-to-api-using-nifi/59449842#59449842)