# How to add external jar to nifi cluster?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to add an external JAR to my nifi cluster.
I am following the codes of this post: [Nifi multipart form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122809/nifi-multipart-form)
The script body is exactly the same as the one in the post except that it is without Grab phrase.
I have downloaded the jars: httpcore-4.3.2 and httpmime-4.5.9.jar from maven repo and I have put them into local file system of the cluster.
Then I gave the location of these jars to the additional classpath of ExecuteGroovyScript.
However i have an error of "unable to resolve class ContentType".
It seems it never found the jar.

Someone helps please.

FYI: I am working on a cluster which I cannot add the external jars directly to /lib so i cannot use grab.

[image: error in the cluster]

and here is the error from nifi-app.log of my local nifi:

```
2021-05-17 17:38:44,825 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=7a78065f-0179-1000-2e4b-daefbdcf006a] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:65)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at Scriptffffffffea61d3da$_run_closure1.doCall(Scriptffffffffea61d3da.groovy:10)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.GroovySessionFile$5.process(GroovySessionFile.java:176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2923)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.ProcessSessionWrap.write(ProcessSessionWrap.java:823)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.SessionFile.write(SessionFile.java:93)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.GroovySessionFile.write(GroovySessionFile.java:174)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.flow.GroovySessionFile$write.call(Unknown Source)
    at Scriptffffffffea61d3da.run(Scriptffffffffea61d3da.groovy:9)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:449)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: what's the full error message in the log file? - it's possible you did not put all the dependencies to cluster.... how you specified the additional classpath for several jar files? do you have any error messages in log files when you are setting additional classpath?

Comment: i bet you did not put all required libraries into a local folder to make httpmime-4.5.9.jar working

Comment: hello daggett. I just added the screenshot of the error. I put the location of the jars like this: '/home/username/httpmime-4.5.9.jar;/home/username/httpcore-4.3.2.jar' in the Additional classpath.

Answer (score 0):

as i can see you have to include more libraries to use `httpmime-4.5.9`

```
org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/jars/httpmime-4.5.9.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.5.9.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.4.11.jar
commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.11.jar
```

you can run the following code in groovy console to determine all libraries required for one dependency:

```js
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpmime', version='4.5.9')
import groovy.grape.Grape

def grape = Grape.getInstance()
def r = grape.listDependencies(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
println grape.resolve(r[0]).join('\n')
```

Comment: I have tried to add all the five jars into the additional classpath but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Just another info. I have tried to build a local nifi of the same version: 1.9 and tried with only two jars: httpmime and httpcore. It works. there is no such class not resolved error however when I start the flow it give me a runtime error: "ExecuteGroovyScript[id=7a78065f-0179-1000-2e4b-daefbdcf006a] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity"

Comment: Then probably nifi does not have access to the folder. Check messages before error message.

Comment: I cannot either access /logs. Is there a workaround that I can see the error messages?

Comment: Not really. You could try to write a groovy code to read the directory where jar files are located.

Comment: Any thought on why there is NoClassDefFoundError? My flow is simple: generateflowfile -> executeGroovyScript. But it gives me a runtime error NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: without access to error log no way to answer correctly. or dependencies missing, or no access to jar files. try to give access to jar files to all users.

Comment: Hey daggett. I just updated the error log of my local nifi. Please take a look. Thank you.