# how to call from apache NiFi processor 'InvokeHTTP' POST with MultipartFile formdata to remote API

Tags: apache-nifi

I have have two request formdata param. one parameter is named **file** which is multipart and another is named **acno** which is string. Here is the postman image:

[image]

**Postman request is working fine. This postman request, I want to process using Apache Nifi. Here I have tried to use below image in apache nifi:**

[image]

**But request not working. followed below steps details Screens:**

**1. GetFile Configure:**

[image]

**2. Update Attribute:**

[image]

**3. AttributeToJson:**

[image]

**4. InvokeHTTP config:**

[image]

I follow steps above screen --> **Getfile->UpdateAtribute->AttributeToJson->InvokHttp**

What is the wrong of my configuration?

Please help me...

Comment: to send multipart you have to transform content to this format.  i'm still using this kind of script to make transformation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122809/nifi-multipart-form/57204862#57204862

Comment: @daggett thanks for your reply. I have solved the problem using post:form:acno